# Why is this loop ending early?

Tags: c

So for a recent USACO problem, the user had to read in a file with Row Col, for the first line, and then following that, lines with a series of either #'s or .'s . When using C to try this, I find that my array that stores the contents of the file is ending prematurely, midway through the 4th row of a 5 row file. There are no errors when executing.

```
#include <stdio.h>       
int main()
{
    FILE *fin = fopen("crosswords.in", "r");
    FILE *fout = fopen("crosswords.out","w");
    int N, M;
    fscanf(fin,"%d %d", &N, &M);
    int arr[N][M];
    char c;
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < N;i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            fscanf(fin,"%c", &c);
            arr[i][j] = c;
            printf("%c", c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That is the code. The file is:

```
5 3
...
#..
...
..#
.##
```

The output is:

```
...
#..
...
..
```

The first line is a newline, but the code block doesnt show it

Why does the code stop early?
EDITS:

When I print N and M, I get 5 and 3
I am using a 2d array because you have to perform calculations based on the position. The problem is: http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=488.

I also don't know how to respond to comments

Comment: print `N` and `M` and say what the output is

Comment: why aren't you using an array of chars if you're reading chars?

Comment: What about new lines? It seems you have new line chars (5 lines). And `\n` codes are read as next char `%c`. Even there can be `\r\n` at end of each line (2 more chars).

Comment: You need to add one or two `fscanf(fin,"%c", &c)` **after** the inner loop, in order to scan the one or two newline characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\n` is also a `char` and is read by `fscanf`. To skip `\n` try this:

```
fscanf(fin," %c", &c);  
//          ^A space before %c can skip any number of white-spaces
```

and use a `printf("\n");` statement after the inner loop.

Comment: Yes, this worked. So a space before a format thing can skip any number of whitespace? Well that's useful. Why is that?

Comment: No. This works only for `%c`. Not for other format specification.